# Show help text above input and below title of a cck field

Tags: 7, entities

Hi I am working with a drupal 7 I have created multiple content types for the site. I want to display the content of the help text of a particular cck field above the input field instead of displaying it below the input field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use [template_preprocess_field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7) ( preprocess for theme_field ) to adjust the position of field description/help text.

Cheers

Comment: Doesn't this only affect the view of a node, rather than the form used to create/edit it?

Answer (score 1):

There's a module for that: [Label Help](http://www.drupal.org/project/label_help)

> In normal rendering of Drupal form fields, the field's "description"
>   (i.e., its help text) gets placed below the form's input element,
>   which is not necessarily the most useful place to place it. On
>   textarea form fields that enable multiple input formats, for example,
>   the field's help text gets placed below the text format selector and
>   tips. This means that website users are unlikely to notice and read
>   the help text.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please avoid link-only answer. The least you should do is to quote relevant part of module's page to show how exactly it answers the question.